# understanding of Volatile.Read/Write

Tags: c#, volatile, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to understand the C# Volatile class.

As i read:

- The `Volatile.Write` method forces the value in location to be written
  to at the point of the call. In addition, any earlier program-order
  loads and stores must occur before the call to Volatile.Write.
- The `Volatile.Read` method forces the value in location to be read from
  at the point of the call. In addition, any later program-order loads
  and stores must occur after the call to Volatile.Read.

Is that means the in the case of:

```
internal sealed class ThreadsSharingData {    
    private Int32 m_flag = 0;
    private Int32 m_value = 0;
    // This method is executed by one thread
    public void Thread1() {        
        // Note: 5 must be written to m_value before 1 is written to m_flag
        m_value = 5;
        Volatile.Write(ref m_flag, 1);        
    }

    // This method is executed by another thread
    public void Thread2() {        
        // Note: m_value must be read after m_flag is read
        if (Volatile.Read(ref m_flag) == 1)
        Console.WriteLine(m_value);        
    }    
}
```

the cpu will wait for the commands before `Volatile.Write(ref m_flag, 1);` before starting to write to `m_flag`?

And how is that helps the threads synchronization?

Comment: It is only relevant on processors with a weak memory model, the kind where acquire and release semantics matter.  There are few left but ARM cores.  It is *not* a substitute for proper synchronization, writing thread-safe code without synchronization is a very advanced concept.  Otherwise already covered well in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039188/volatile-vs-volatileread-write).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the cpu will wait for the commands before Volatile.Write(ref m_flag, 1); before starting to write to m_flag?

Eeeh, kinda. A better way to phrase this is: it's guaranteed that, if any other thread sees `m_flag` set to 1, they will also see `m_value` set to 5.

> And how is that helps the threads synchronization?

I wouldn't say it helps with synchronization - but it does help with achieving correctness.

If you weren't using volatile reads/writes, it would be possible for the compiler/runtime/cpu to reorder the two instructions in the `Thread1` method, and the program would be able to print either 0, 5 or nothing at all.

With the volatile reads/writes, the program will print either 5 or nothing at all, but *never* 0. Which is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

> How does that help thread synchronization?

It does not help thread synchronization in the sense of setting the order in which their commands execute. It lets you ensure that a concurrent thread observes changes to values in memory in a specific order, in cases when a particular order is important for the logic of your program.

> [Does] the CPU wait for the commands before `Volatile.Write(ref m_flag, 1);` before starting to write to `m_flag`?

No, the command to write to `m_value` has already executed. However, its results may not be visible outside the CPU's core - in particular, a thread running on a different core might read an old value from `m_value` *after* the command that wrote `5` to it has finished executing. This is because the new value may be in the cache of the CPU, not in the memory.

If you write

```
m_value = 5;
m_flag = 1;
```

instead of `Volatile.Write(ref m_flag, 1)` the other core may see the writes in a different order: first it would see that `m_flag` became `1`, and after that it would see that `m_value` became `5`. If your other thread uses the value of `m_flag` to judge the validity of `m_value`, the logic may be broken: for example, `Thread2` may occasionally print zero.